# Unable to download files from FTP server

Tags: java, shell, ftp

I've created Java function that downloads files from FTP server. It works fine from my local machine. But I need to run it under linux server (means another host and port). And the function gives an error

```
The collection, array, map, iterator, or enumeration portion of a for statement cannot be null
```

Caused in a line with the code:

```
for(String f : ftpNames) {
    ftpclient.retrieveFile(f, os); // os is OutputStream
}
```

So it doesn't see the files...
I added

```
ftpclient.enterRemotePassiveMode();
```

And `ftpclient.getPassiveHost()` returns `227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,204,15)`

Tried to list and download them via **shell** - it works.

How should I modify my code to solve the problem? Thanks.

**UPD**. I got log from FTP server I'm trying to get files from, and there is such string:

```
 425 Cannot open data connection
```

Full code:

```
static boolean ftpFilesDownload(String ip, int port, String login, String passwd, String ftpdir, String localdir) throws IOException {
        Boolean result = false;

        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        String separator = File.separator;


        try {                             
            client.connect(ip, port);    
            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
            client.login(login, passwd);
            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());

            client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(1000*60*5);
            client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(1000*60*5);
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            System.out.println("client setFileType success");    

            client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpdir);
            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
            client.printWorkingDirectory();
            System.out.println("directory changed");                                 

            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
            System.out.println(ftpFiles);                          

            String[] ftpNames = client.listNames();
            System.out.println("the files are " + Arrays.toString(ftpNames)); // so null here...
              for(String f : ftpNames) {                
            String localfile = localdir + f;
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(localfile);
            try  {
                result = client.retrieveFile(f, os);
                System.out.println("DOWNLOADING STARTED);
                System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
                client.noop();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);                    
                result = false;
            }
            finally {
                if(os != null)
                    os.close();
                }
            }
            client.logout();
            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of `ftpNames`? That is what it is complaining about.

Comment: `String[] ftpNames = ftpclient.listNames();`

Comment: I can't seem to link to it via the android app, but searching for "java ftpclient listfiles null" on Google turned up a stackoverflow answer which looked useful, title "java - Issue with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient listFiles". It suggests that you need to specify a particular entry parser, since there is no single standard.

Comment: Thanks... but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As the error message explains, you're trying to iterate over a `null` object. You should check for this (or make sure an empty Iterable is used perhaps)

If this is an execptional (error) state, I'd check for this explicitly and throw some kind of runtime exception, e.g.:

```
if (ftpNames == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use a null set of FTP servers");
}

for (String f : ftpNames) {
    ftpclient.retrieveFile(f, os); // os is OutputStream
}
```

Alternatively you could try to continue with no FTP servers, but seems a bit pointless.

Comment: I can see that the `ftpNames` is null. I can't figure out what causes it

Comment: Please can you add details of what ftpclient is (i.e. which ftp client library you are using)?

Comment: You haven't posted imports, so it still isn't clear what client libraries you are using, so i can't look up javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **ftpclient.enterLocalActiveMode();**